# Struggling with INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables of data, one named actor, and one named customer. What I am trying to achieve is getting a list of customers & actors that have the same last name. Names will be ordered by the last name.

The problem I get is that my WHERE line appears to return blank results

```
-- the NOW()'Jordan_Rasmussen' is simply there so that instructors will see that its me when I screenshot the results, as their instructions state.

SELECT NOW()'Jordan_Rasmussen',
CONCAT(c.first_name, ' ', c.last_name) AS customer_name,
CONCAT(a.first_name, ' ', a.last_name) AS actor_name
FROM customer AS c
INNER JOIN actor AS a ON c.customer_id = a.actor_id
WHERE c.last_name LIKE a.last_name
ORDER BY c.last_name;
```

Comment: Do you get a number of `blank results`, or does your *query* return *0 results*? Have a look at the join-condition. If you still got a question, disclose more about the IDs used in *customer* and *actor*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must join on last names and not on ids:

```
SELECT NOW() AS `Jordan_Rasmussen`,
CONCAT(c.first_name, ' ', c.last_name) AS customer_name,
CONCAT(a.first_name, ' ', a.last_name) AS actor_name
FROM customer AS c INNER JOIN actor AS a 
ON c.last_name = a.last_name
ORDER BY c.last_name;
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much. I guess I had a misunderstanding of the INNER JOIN itself.

Answer (score 0):

Forpas has already provided a solution. Just keep in mind that your inner join will provide the combination of records whose id are equal:

```
create table customer(
       customer_id integer, 
       first_name varchar(100), 
       last_name varchar(100)
);
insert into customer(customer_id, first_name, last_name)
values (1, 'henry','fonda'), 
       (2, 'kirk','douglas'),
       (3, 'john','houston');      

create table actor(
         actor_id integer, 
         first_name varchar(100), 
         last_name varchar(100)
);
insert into actor(actor_id, first_name, last_name)
values (1, 'jane','fonda'), 
       (2, 'angelica', 'houston') ,
       (3, 'michael','douglas');
```

so

```
SELECT NOW()'Jordan_Rasmussen',
   CONCAT(c.first_name, ' ', c.last_name) AS customer_name,
   CONCAT(a.first_name, ' ', a.last_name) AS actor_name
FROM customer AS c
INNER JOIN actor AS a ON c.customer_id = a.actor_id
-- WHERE c.last_name LIKE a.last_name
ORDER BY c.last_name;
```

Will return:

```
|  Jordan_Rasmussen   | customer_name |    actor_name    |
|---------------------|---------------|------------------|
| 2019-11-30 21:46:15 | kirk douglas  | angelica houston |
| 2019-11-30 21:46:15 | henry fonda   | jane fonda       |
| 2019-11-30 21:46:15 | john houston  | michael douglas  |
```

If you filter also by rows having the same last_name, there's only one match:
(also, LIKE without '%' is pretty much like using '=' except for wildcard characters.

```
SELECT NOW()'Jordan_Rasmussen',
   CONCAT(c.first_name, ' ', c.last_name) AS customer_name,
   CONCAT(a.first_name, ' ', a.last_name) AS actor_name
FROM customer AS c
INNER JOIN actor AS a ON c.customer_id = a.actor_id
WHERE c.last_name LIKE a.last_name
ORDER BY c.last_name;

|  Jordan_Rasmussen   | customer_name |    actor_name    |
|---------------------|---------------|------------------|
| 2019-11-30 21:46:15 | henry fonda   | jane fonda       |
```

<kbd>[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9e7cb6822289e216c11b265e55b87a0b)</kbd>

BTW, your first field is like `SELECT NOW() as 'Jordan_Rasmussen'`. Perhaps there's a comma missing there?

Comment: Thank you for that. I'm new with the JOIN concept, so it really helped to specifically see why what I was doing is wrong. My school is having us do a bit of the software side of things, and a bit of the hardware side of things to help us decide what field we would like to choose. I have a lot of fun with the software side of things, but its always leaving me scratching my head.